# TYPO3 9.5 URL Routes

Tags: url-rewriting, typo3, typo3-9.x

I have an old real_url.conf (from RealURL TYPO3 7.6). Now I have updated the system to TYPO3 9.5 and I need again the speaking URLs for my extension.

Unfortunately, I don't have that yet, that's why I ask for advice here.

```
'postVarSets' => array(
            '_DEFAULT' => array (
                "in" => array(
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'pm_zahnarztprofiles[ort]'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'pm_zahnarztprofiles[stadtteil]'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'pm_zahnarztprofiles[name]'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'pm_zahnarztprofiles[id]'
                    ),
                ),
                "page" => array(
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'pm_zahnarztprofiles[page]'
                    )
                ),
                "sitemap" => array(
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'pm_zahnarztprofiles[sitemap]'
                    )
                ),
                "html_sitemap" => array(
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'pm_zahnarztprofiles[html_sitemap]'
                    )
                ),
                "search" => array(
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'pm_zahnarztprofiles[search]'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'pm_zahnarztprofiles[page]'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
```

Comment: Did you have a look at the [official documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/9.5/en-us/ApiOverview/Routing/AdvancedRoutingConfiguration.html)? Can you post a snippet of your site configuration about what you tried so far?

Comment: Yeah, but to be honest, I can't handle it. I don't have anything yet.

Comment: Please add the information if that is an Extbase plugin. If yes, start here https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/9.5/en-us/ApiOverview/Routing/AdvancedRoutingConfiguration.html#extbase-plugin-enhancer - pick a single, simple route for the beginning, e.g. "page".